# NUnit testlist specifying tests to exclude

Tags: c#, nunit, nunit-console

So I have a fairly large amount of UI tests I kick off using NUnit, and in order to control what tests are ran in what environments, we use a test list.

The test list currently contains a list of tests that *are* included in the test run, but I would rather it specify tests that it should no run instead since the amount is much lower and will be easier to keep up with. I use the NUnit command line runner, this is my command.

```
"Project\bin\KahuaLFT.dll" --testlist="Project\Main\Utilities\TestSuites\BETA.txt" --where "cat = 'Smoke'" --params "Env=BETA"
```

The BETA.txt lists out all the tests that will be included, but is there a way to change this so it instead ignores the tests specified in the --testlist?

Comment: Doesn't seem to be anything [in the docs](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Console-Command-Line) to suggest that's possible.

Comment: Yep I would agree with you there, hoping there is someone out there that may have a creative solution :D

Answer (score 0):

I was looking at doing something similar, and while I never implemented it I thought I'd share my idea...

- execute the nunit-console-runner with the --where parameter and without the --testlist parameter, and add the --explore parameter.  This will not run any tests but will return the list of tests to be executed

So for your example it would be:

```
nunit-console.exe "Project\bin\KahuaLFT.dll" --where "cat = 'Smoke'" --expore="testlist.txt;format=cases"
```

- Take the text file returned by the previous statement, open with Powershell, or whatever you prefer, and remove any entries that match your list in BETA.txt
- Call nunit-console again, passing in the modified testlist.txt  as the --testlist parameter